# Angular 2 / 4 / 5 - Ahead-of-time compilation how to

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to bootstrap my Angular 2 RC5 application following this guide
https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/ngmodule.html
Below is my code

```
import { AppModuleNgFactory } from './app.module.ngfactory';
import {platformBrowser} from "@angular/platform-browser";

platformBrowser().bootstrapModuleFactory(AppModuleNgFactory);
```

However , when I tried to compile typescript code, I got the following error

> app\main.ts(1,36): error TS2307: Cannot find module
>   './app.module.ngfactory'.

How can I generate the **app.module.ngfactory** file? Which tool should I use?

Comment: For a barebones solution github.com/blacksonic/angular2-aot-webpack , and an alternative with Webpack plugins (no need to modify entry point) github.com/blacksonic/angular2-aot-cli-webpack-plugin (internally uses plugin og Angular CLI)

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Both the JIT and AOT compilers generate an **AppModuleNgFactory** class from the same AppModule source code.

The JIT compiler creates that factory class on the fly, in memory, in the browser. The AOT compiler outputs the factory to a physical file that we're importing here in the static version of main.ts

At a high level, `@angular/compiler-cli` provides a wrapper around Typescript’s `tsc` compiler, and both AoT compiles your application’s code, and then transpiles your application’s Typescript to Javascript:

```
$ ngc -p src
```

This generates a new file for each component and module ( called an **NgFactory** )

**To run your app in AoT mode**, 
all that’s required is changing your main.ts file from

```
import {platformBrowserDynamic} from ‘@angular/platform-browser-dynamic’
import {MyAppModule} from ‘./app’
platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(MyAppModule);
```

to

```
import {platformBrowser} from ‘@angular/platform-browser’
import {MyAppModuleNgFactory} from ‘./app.ngfactory’ //generated code
platformBrowser().bootstrapModuleFactory(MyAppModuleNgFactory);
```

---

**EDIT:**

To use `ngc` command, first install these-

```
$ npm install @angular/compiler-cli typescript@next @angular/platform-server @angular/compiler
```

`ngc` is a drop-in replacement for `tsc` which you will find it in- `./node_modules/.bin/ngc` folder.

Comment: Do you know how to install ngc? It seems that -p is used with typescript config file rather than source code folder?

Comment: @ToanNguyen Check my EDIT answer. For more details, refer Install and Use section on this link - https://github.com/angular/angular/tree/master/modules/%40angular/compiler-cli

Comment: When I run ngc, it does not generate .ngfactory files, instead it only generates .metadata.json files.

Comment: I found this: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/10792. Many users are reporting that ngc does not work on Windows.

Comment: @Sanket can you please also update the answer with instructions for those who are not using @angular/compiler-cli but are building apps manually (e.g. people using ASP.Net and manually creating components, ngModules routes etc.)

Comment: @Sanket the order of events in your answer is unclear to me. Do you modify `main.ts` before you run `ngc`? If so you get errors about a non existent `MyAppModuleNgFactory`.  On the other hand, do you modify `main.ts` after you run `ngc`? If so, the Javascript files will not reflect the new `main.ts`.  I'm stuck in a circular reference logic

Comment: I am also getting the error `Cannot find module './app.ngfactory'` after following those steps.

Comment: @Sanket as of today, probably it is good to also refer to original project [here](https://github.com/blacksonic/angular2-aot-webpack)

Comment: @ngtools/webpack with Angular5 no longer requires a different main.ts AOT, you can use the same main.ts for both JIT and AOT

Answer (score 28):

**2017 UPDATE**

As of Janurary 2017 **If using [angular-cli](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli)**, AOT compiling is now the default compilation method when running the following command `ng build --prod` with no code change requirements.

If you want to disable AOT and instead use JIT in production, then you can use `ng build --prod --no-aot`.

Source: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/4138

---

This means that you can still use JIT compiling whilst developing (will compile faster so pretty handy) with `ng build` and leave your `.ts` as something like this:

```
// The browser platform with a compiler
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

// The app module
import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';

// Compile and launch the module
platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

---

**To Summarise:**

```
ng build                    // build with JIT
ng build --prod --no-aot    // build with JIT 
ng build --prod             // build with AOT
```

Comment: How do you configure that with Webpack?

Comment: @Atieh What are you reffering to ?

Comment: @Zze Does this mean we dont have to use these steps mentioned in the angular docs https://angular.io/guide/aot-compiler#compile-with-aot to achieve aot? I couldnt find any clear statement about this. Could you point me to the details. Thanks in advance !

Comment: @AshwiniMaddala I agree that this is slightly conflicting. You do *NOT* have to edit the `.tsconfig`. angular-cli handles this process for you. "AoT compilation is a good technique which is already integrated as part of the angular-seed and angular-cli" - http://blog.mgechev.com/2016/08/14/ahead-of-time-compilation-angular-offline-precompilation/