# Angular 2 Ahead-of-Time Compiler with gulp-typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, deployment, gulp, gulp-typescript

`Angular 2 rc 6` written in `Typescript 2.0.2`

I'm trying to learn Ahead-of-Time compilation [as outlined here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38932193/angular-2-ahead-of-time-compilation-how-to).  It seems simple enough:

- Run `ngc` instead of the Typescript compiler to generate `.ngfactory.ts` files
- Replace `platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule()` with `platformBrowser().bootstrapModuleFactory()`

I'm not sure how to apply the first step to my setup. I use `gulp-typescript 2.13.6` to compile my typescript to JavaScript.

**gulpfile.js**

```
var ts = require('gulp-typescript');
var tsProject = ts.createProject('tsconfig.json', {
    //Use TS version installed by NPM instead of gulp-typescript's built-in
    typescript: require('typescript')
});
gulp.task('build-ts', function () {
    return gulp.src(appDev + '**/*.ts')
        .pipe(ts(tsProject))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(appProd));
});
```

So my question is; how do I integrate the instructions into my tooling? How do I get `gulp-typescript` to use the Angular Compiler?  I've tried:

```
var tsProject = ts.createProject('tsconfig.json', {
    typescript: require('@angular/compiler') // or '@angular/compiler-cli'
});
```

This throws errors without ever running `ngc`.  I also tried

```
var tsProject = ts.createProject('tsconfig.json', {
    typescript: require('./node_modules/.bin/ngc')
});
```

This does execute `ngc` but immediately throws error:

> SyntaxError: Unexpected string at ngc:2: basedir=$(dirname "$(echo "$0" | sed -e 's,\,/,g')")

I suspect this is because no source directory is passed to `ngc` (the required command is `ngc -p path/to/project`)

Basically, is there a way to use `gulp-typescript` to have a one step build process? (generate `.ngfactory.ts` files, then compile all to JavaScript)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I imagine the reason why the `typescript: require(..)` is not working is because gulp-typescript looks for something called `typescript` or tries to run the command `tsc`, and since the angular compiler command is `ngc`, it doesn't find it.

For now, if your project is just as simple as compiling it, you can just run the command from gulp like so:

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;

gulp.task('task', function (cb) {
  exec('ngc -p "<path to your tsconfig.json>"', function (err, stdout, stderr) {
    console.log(stdout);
    console.log(stderr);
    cb(err);
  });
});
```

This requires that you have your `tsconfig.json` set up correctly, with the potential extra options that Google talk about [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/tree/master/modules/@angular/compiler-cli), under the Configuration heading.

If you need the more complex functionality that the gulp-typescript package provides, I'm afraid you're either going to have to develop it yourself, or wait for someone else to.

Comment: Thanks William.  Please add a few more details:  What are `cb` and `cb(err)`? Do I need to install a `child_process` plugin? Does the path include the name `tsconfig.json` or is it just path to the directory?

Comment: `cb` I believe stands for callback, so in that code snippet, `cb(err)` simply passes the error function into the callback function. I adapted that snippet from the information [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-exec). `child_process` is a built-in module of gulp 4.0 and above. Concerning the path, this is from the [Google link](https://github.com/angular/angular/tree/master/modules/@angular/compiler-cli) above, "It accepts a `-p` flag which points to a `tsconfig.json` file, or a directory containing one." so, either.

Answer (score 3):

I was trying to get this to work as well and William Gilmour's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39370453/2086616) helped a lot.

I extended it a little to run a local `ngc` installation (like the angular 2 [example](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/aot-compiler.html#!#compile) that runs the one in `node_modules/.bin`), and which works both on Linux and Windows systems:

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
var os = require('os');

gulp.task('build-ts', function (cb) {

    var cmd = os.platform() === 'win32' ? 
        'node_modules\\.bin\\ngc' : './node_modules/.bin/ngc';

    exec(cmd, function (err, stdout, stderr) {
        console.log(stdout);
        console.log(stderr);
        cb(err);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the cross-platform version of the gulpfile, which I am currently using for Ahead-Of-Time (AOT) compilation with angular 2:

```
//jshint node:true
//jshint esversion: 6
'use strict';

...

// helper function for running ngc and tree shaking tasks
const run_proc = (cmd, callBack, options) => {
        process.stdout.write(stdout);
        process.stdout.write(stderr);
        callBack(err);
    });
};


gulp.task('ngc', ['css', 'html', 'ts'], cb => {
    let cmd  = 'node_modules/.bin/ngc -p tsconfig-aot.json';
    if (isWin) {
        cmd  = '"node_modules/.bin/ngc" -p tsconfig-aot.json';
    }
    return run_proc(cmd, cb);
});
```

Feel free to check out the entire example of the [Tour of Heroes (ToH)](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/) example with gulp.js on my github repo: [ng2-heroes-gulp](https://github.com/ibqn/ng2-heroes-gulp/blob/master/gulpfile.js)

This is for sure the short term solution, the long term solution for me will be the gulp-ngc plugin.