# Angular2 SystemJs, Ahead of Time Compilation with Gulp

Tags: angular, angular2-services, angular2-aot, angular2-compiler

Can anyone please guide how to use Gulp for Ahead of Time compilation of a Angular2 project that uses SystemJs. I mean to automate all steps mentioned in https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/aot-compiler.html

i.e. generate NgFactories, Treeshaking and bundling?

Comment: Please refer to the below link, I hope it will give you a start. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39340283/angular-2-ahead-of-time-compiler-with-gulp-typescript

Comment: Thank you Vikram, the actual issue is the steps after generating the ngfactory files

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to use gulp for that. You just "hide" the commands behind an npm "package.json" script command. (If you really want to fire cmd with gulp you can use the shell js gulp plugin for example). After you have the output of AoT you need any tool which takes the output and can work with that. You have to create bundles to get the application in production state. Therefore you can use rollup.js or webpack. You do not need to take gulp anymore. However, there are gulp-rollup and gulp-webpack plugins out there. But using webpack or rollup.js after doing AoT without gulp should give you what you want.