# Angular 2 Ahead-of-Time compiler: must I make all class properties public?

Tags: angular, typescript, deployment, npm, angular2-aot

`Angular 2 rc 6`, `typescript 2`, `node 4.5.0`, `npm 2.15.9` on `Windows 7`

I'm trying to move from Just-in-Time to Ahead-of-Time compilation and I'm relying on these resources:

- [Angular 2 - Ahead-of-time compilation how to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38932193/angular-2-ahead-of-time-compilation-how-to)
- https://github.com/angular/angular/tree/master/modules/@angular/compiler-cli#angular-template-compiler

I understand that I need to run the compiler `ngc` to generate `ngfactory.ts` files, and that I need to change `main.ts` to use `platformBrowser` instead of `platformBrowserDynamic` to bootstrap. I've hit a roadblock though and don't know how to proceed.

**1.** I've confirmed that the App runs without errors using Just-in-Time compilation. My `main.ts` is:

```
enableProdMode();
platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

**2.** I clear all my app files from my production folder, but keep 3rd party libraries (eg: Angular 2, Angular 2 Material)

**3.** I run `"node_modules/.bin/ngc" -p ./` This runs with no output to the console. I see an `.ngfactory.ts` file for each of my `.ts` components and modules. I also see a `.css.shim.ts` file for each of my `.css` that held component styles.  In addition, `.js` and `.js.map` files have been transpiled and placed in the production directory

**4.** If I try to run the app at this point, I see `404 not found` errors for all the `.html` files that held component templates

**5.** I manually move all template files (`.html`) to production dir and run the App. It runs fine, but it still uses Just-in-Time compilation (255 requests, including `compiler.umd.js`)

**6.** I change my `main.ts` to:

```
enableProdMode();
platformBrowser().bootstrapModuleFactory(AppModuleNgFactory);
```

On its own, this makes no difference since the new code has not been compiled. However, I don't know what to do from here.

Should I run `ngc` again? If so I get lots of errors of the type:

```
Error at C:/path/to/notify.component.ngfactory.ts:113:41: Property 'visible' is private and only accessible within class 'NotifyComponent'
... (many more like that with lots of properties from lots of components)
Compilation failed
```

Does using AoT compilation mean that I must make all my class properties public? Am I missing a step?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

For a given component all its members (methods, properties) accessed by its template **must** be public in the ahead-of-time compilation scenario. This is due to the fact that a template is turned into a TS class. A generated class and a component are 2 separate classes now and you can't access private members cross-class.

In short: you can't access private members in your templates if you want to use ahead-of-time compilation.

Comment: That's what I figured as well. Wish ionic docs make this clearer as `convert private variable to public` sounds kind of scary

Comment: I wish the template TS class implemented (inherited?) the related Component class. Then we could use `protected`.

Answer (score 4):

So is too, in Final release of Angular 2 whit Ionic2 RC1

A workaround for Fields could be to use getters without setters

```typescript
protected _myField: any;

get myField(): any { 
  return this._myField; 
}
```

You can also see **other JiT to AoT considerations** to adapt your code in [this blog of Isaac Mann](https://medium.com/@isaacplmann/making-your-angular-2-library-statically-analyzable-for-aot-e1c6f3ebedd5)

1. const lambda => export function
2. default export => named export
3. private, protected accessors should be changed to public for any members accessed from template
4. dynamic component template => static template
5. moduleId should be set on components with templateUrl