# AoT NGC / Angular2: Property is protected and only accessible within class Error

Tags: angular, ionic2

In on of our components in our Angular 2 / Ionic 2 (final/rc0) project I am using:

```
protected contentTarget: ViewContainerRef;

ngOnInit() {
        this.contentTarget.createComponent(componentFactory);
    }
```

AoT Compiler says:

```
Error at ....: Property 'contentTarget' is protected and only accessible within class 'IncludeTemplateComponent' and its subclasses.
```

Variable (property) is not used anywhere else in whole project.

So... could anybody shed some light on this, is createComponent factory passing the contentTarget variable to its child or why does compiler does not like protected here? Are protected variables "forbidden" in all of Angular2 now?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39379451/1871890)

> For a given component all its members (methods, properties) accessed
>   by its template must be public in the ahead-of-time compilation
>   scenario. This is due to the fact that a template is turned into a TS
>   class. A generated class and a component are 2 separate classes now
>   and you can't access private members cross-class.

My take is that `contentTarget` is used by the template engine and thus, must be public for AOT to work.