# Angular2 and Heroku AOT build - Supplied parameters do not match signature of call target

Tags: angular, typescript, heroku, typechecking

My Angular2 app has been building, compiling and running fine for months now. The package.json has not changed in months either.

Suddenly today when I deploy to Heroku I get a whole host of errors I have never seen before.

For example:

```
ERROR in /tmp/build_2370f712cb3c370be2ee07c793ee7c1e/src/$$_gendir/app/products
/product-form/product-form.component.ngfactory.ts (93,9): 
 Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target.
```

I have no idea which line it is referring to in the actual component. This code worked and built a few days ago.

I contacted Heroku support and they do not know why this suddenly started happening.

Judging from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39378643/angular-2-ahead-of-time-compiler-must-i-make-all-class-properties-public?noredirect=1&lq=1), it seems to be something to do with AOT compilation. But I thought Heroku always did that. Somewhat confused here.

If I locally force AOT compile with `ng build --aot --prod` none of these errors occur.

Notice that the error is referring to line 93 of an 'ngfactory.ts' file - so how can I find what the ACTUAL line no is in the component?

**EDIT**

I created a brand new project, updated everything to Angular 4.1.3. Each time I added a new component I pushed to Heroku. Everything has been fine (about 30 components so far) until the latest component, which now gives the same error EXCEPT it is not referring to `ngFactory.ts` file, but to the html file!

```
ERROR in ng:///tmp/build_48fd9e2da47f9df65e24dab60d5fc080/src/app/
proposal-list/proposal-list.component.html (8,7): 
Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target.
```

Here is the file, line 8 is the closing `</pagination-controls>`. This makes no sense - what supplied parameters is it referring to?!

```
<div class="row fb-pager-row">
  <div class="col-md-4 text-left fb-pager-records">
    {{total$ | async | i18nPlural:pluralizeMapQuote}}
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-8 text-right">
    <pagination-controls class="fb-pager" autoHide="true"
      (pageChange)="goToPage($event)" id="server" previousLabel="Prev" maxSize="7">
    </pagination-controls>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="list-group">
  <fb-proposal-list-item *ngFor="let proposal of items$ | async | 
     paginate: { id: 'server', itemsPerPage: 10, currentPage: currentPage, totalItems: total$ | async }" 
    [proposal]="proposal" (proposalDataChanged)="handleDataChanged($event)">
  </fb-proposal-list-item>
</div>
```

If I remove the pagination controls entirely, it builds. So I am assuming there is something borked in this [third party control](https://github.com/michaelbromley/ngx-pagination#module-format).

Comment: Can you share the html and the ts of the component?

Comment: @echonax Its a huge amount of code, I'd rather figure out how I can generate the factory files locally so I can then see which file it is referring to.

Comment: @echonax Here is a link, I made the repo public for now: https://github.com/rmcsharry/floorbook/tree/master/src/app/products  It is the last component in the list there, products-component.ts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it is line 7 that has the problem, not line 8.

I finally figured out that:

```
(pageChange)="goToPage($event)"
```

has 2 parameters, not one. So

```
(pageChange)="goToPage($event, true)"
```

fixes the error.