# Error trying to install the Angular compiler-cli (ngc)

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli, angular-module

I'm trying to follow the Angular Modules tutorial [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/ngmodule.html), and I've run into the same trouble this person had [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38932193/angular-2-ahead-of-time-compilation-how-to). So I'm trying their solution, but running into trouble getting the compiler-cli (ngc) to work. When I try to install with:

```
npm install @angular/compiler-cli typescript@next @angular/platform-server @angular/compiler
```

I get:

```
modules@0.0.0 ~/Documents/Work/modules
├── @angular/compiler@2.4.1 
├─┬ @angular/compiler-cli@2.4.1 
│ └── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY typescript@^2.0.2
├── @angular/platform-server@2.4.1 
└── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY typescript@2.2.0-dev.20161230 invalid
```

The TypeScript version in my package.json is:

```
"typescript": "~2.0.3"
```

Should I just install an older version of TypeScript in my project? And what is the best way to do that. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where did you get this `npm install` line? If you look at the [quickstart package.json](https://github.com/angular/quickstart/blob/master/package.json) it uses different version of typescript and a bunch of other `@angular` modules.

Comment: I included a link in my question to where I got that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38932193/angular-2-ahead-of-time-compilation-how-to

Comment: I see. For me the problem is solved when installing with `typescript` instead of `typescript@next`

Comment: Oh wow. That worked! Thanks!

Comment: @NitzanTomer, BTW, still having related issues: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41405101/running-the-angular-compiler-cli-ngc-cannot-find-module-angular-core