# Running the Angular compiler-cli (ngc); Cannot find module '@angular/core'

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli

I've tried installing the Angular compiler-cli (ngc) using:

```
npm install @angular/compiler-cli typescript @angular/platform-server @angular/compiler
```

And the install appears to have worked, but now when I run `ngc -p src`, per the solution to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38932193/angular-2-ahead-of-time-compilation-how-to), I get:

```
module.js:442
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module '@angular/core'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:440:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:388:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:468:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:7:83
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:10:2)
    at Module._compile (module.js:541:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:550:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:458:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:417:12)
```

My project runs fine with `ng serve`. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: If you're using Angular CLI, you don't need to use `ngc` directly. You should use `ng build --aot` for AoT compilation. See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39167817/1377864 for more details.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using Angular CLI already, just use `ng build` and let that worry about calling `ngc` correctly.

If this is about AOT, then do this:

```
ng build -prod -aot
```

and your `/dist/` folder will contain what you need.

**Edit:**
I should add that the question you linked to is for RC5, when Angular CLI was still an infant. There were so many changes since, it's best to always look for answers based on Final.