# How do you bootstrap Angular 9?

Tags: angular, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular9

My app is run in ElectronJs 8 which is the equivalent of Chrome 80 engine.

With Angular 8, I'm using AOT and my `main.ts` has something like this in it:

```
platformBrowser().bootstrapModuleFactory(AppModuleNgFactory)
```

Based on what I've ready, I don't think the `app.module.ngfactory` is generated anymore in Angular 9.

So how do I bootstrap the application? Do I revert to what I had before?

```
platformBrowserDynamic().boostrapModule(AppModule)
```

Am I loosing the AOT benefit by doing so?

Comment: Why would you lose AOT by doing so? Also why did you need `platformBrowser().bootstrapModuleFactory(AppModuleNgFactory)` to get AOT? `aot` is an option in the `angular.json` file

Comment: @GuerricP - I may have a misunderstanding of what the first snippet of code is doing vs the second.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see in this question: [Angular 2 / 4 / 5 - Ahead-of-time compilation how to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38932193/angular-2-4-5-ahead-of-time-compilation-how-to) the line `platformBrowser().bootstrapModuleFactory(AppModuleNgFactory)` is legacy from the very first versions of Angular. It is not required as of January 2017 to get AOT.

Comment: So the answer to my question is that I should be doing this: `platformBrowserDynamic().boostrapModule(AppModule)` for my use case?

Comment: Yes you can safely use this.

Comment: By safely you mean it will work...or is it the "standard Angular 9 practice"?

Comment: I mean this is the standard best practice, `ng` CLI generates this for new projects since a long time, and there is no reason to use something else.